# MATLAB: Using an anonymous function within symsum, then fsolve

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, symbolic-math, mupad

In MATLAB, I wish to define an anonymous function which has a definite sum in it, and another anonymous function in that. Here's a MWE which hopefully describes what I am trying to do:

```
clear; n=1; syms j; a=0; b=sqrt(0.5);
Finv = @(x) logninv(x,a,b);
fun = @(x) 0.5-symsum(Finv(j*x), j, 1, n+1);
fsolve(fun,0.1)
```

The error returned is:

> Error using symfun>validateArgNames (line 211) Second input must be a
>   scalar or vector of unique symbolic variables.
>
> Error in symfun (line 45)
>               y.vars = validateArgNames(inputs);
>
> Error in sym/subsasgn (line 762)
>                   C = symfun(B,[inds{:}]);
>
> Error in logninv (line 60) p(p < 0 | 1 < p) = NaN;
>
> Error in @(x)logninv(x,a,b)
>
> Error in @(x)0.5-symsum(Finv(j*x),j,1,n+1)
>
> Error in fsolve (line 217)
>               fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
>
> Caused by:
>       Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot
>       continue.

For this particular choice of `Finv` I solved it using `eval` and `feval` as follows:

```
clear; n=1; syms j; a=0; b=sqrt(0.5);
Finv = @(x) logninv(x,a,b);
fun = @(x) 0.5-eval(symsum(feval(symengine,'logninv',j*x,a,b), j, 1, n+1));
fsolve(fun,0.1)
```

which produces the answer in this special case because `Finv=@(x) logninv(x,a,b)`, but this defeats the point, which is that I want to be able to define `Finv` as a univariate function of my choice, not necessarily a predefined MuPAD expression like `'logninv'`.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason to use symbolic math? Use sum instead of symsum

Comment: Argh! You are right. This solves it easily:
`fun = @(x) 0.5-sum(Finv([1:n+1]*x));` Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the second variable (i.e., j) as being a symbolic variable with a scalar (numerical) data type. Note in his code, that is only variable is not being initialized.

```
clear; n=1; syms j integer; a=0; b=sqrt(0.5);
```

Alternatively, you can check assumptions on each variable. For example,

```
assumptions(j)
```